# Getting an error in Laravel with response()

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I am new to PHP and Laravel and I have been working on a tutorial. I am trying to pass json to a different route but I get an error saying

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::response()
```

On my route I have

```
Route::get('/nuevo','temm@changeView')
->name('tron');


Route::post('/postaedd','temm@fetchAndDis')
->name('postInfoo');


Route::post('/postedd12321',"temm@pazze")
->name('pazze');
```

On my controller I have

```
    public function pazze(){
        return view('pass');
    }

     public function fetchAndDis(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => "required|min:5",
            "name" => "required|min:1"
        ]);

        $email = $request->input('email');
        $name = $request->input("name");

        $info=[
            'email' => $email,
            "name" => $name
        ];

        return 

        redirect()
        ->route('pazze')
        ->with('info', $info)
        ->response()
        ->json($info, 200);
    }
```

After submitting a form thats when I get the error

Comment: redirect will return a 301, not a json body, instead you should use just `return response(json_encode($info), 200)` or just `return json_encode($info)` if you want to return that json, if not, please explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I am trying to pass $info on the new page, if it was successful then I would get a 200

Comment: in that case, try using the code i gave you

Comment: But how would I pass $info to my pazze route ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need JSON but you can flash data to the session, then you can check if the session has a variable on the other route. Your `fetchAndDis` method can return redirect with the data flashed to the session:

```
return redirect()->route('pazze')->with('info', $info);
```

Then in `pazze` method you can get that flashed session data:

```
$info = $request->session()->get('info');
```

Then you can check what to do with or without the session data.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Responses - Redirects - Redirecting with Flashed Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) `with`

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Sessions - Using the Session - Retrieving Data](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#retrieving-data) `get`

Comment: When i tried to do the return as you said i get another error . `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: it would need to be a `GET` route if you want to redirect to it

Comment: Is there a way to do it with out using a GET route? or what would be best programming practice?